# How do i convert java.net.Socket to WebSocket in wildfly

Tags: sockets, websocket, wildfly

I have an old plain java application which creates a java.net.Socket with an ip adress and a port number - like this :

```
Socket socket = new Socket("", 9999);
```

Since it is not possible to change the other end of the connection we are forced to use sockets in excactly the same manner.

So the application needs to be expanded and converted to run in WildFly and i was wondering if the better way to handle socket connections was to use WebSockets. But all the examples i've seen with ClientEndpoints connects to web service adresses like :

```
Session session = container.connectToServer(MyClientEndpoint.class, new URI("ws://localhost:8080/tictactoeserver/endpoint"));
```

How is it possible to use WebSockets with and ip and port ??

Comment: I guess its not directly possible to use WebSocket standard to connect to java.net.Socket's.

Comment: Well you don't. You should already have a WebSocket to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know its not possible since its 2 different standards